# FFmpeg permission denied CENTOS - PhpVideoToolKit

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm try to execute this PHP code

`exec("/root/bin/ffmpeg -version 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);`

But always the output return permission denied

`Array ( [0] => sh: /root/bin/ffmpeg: Permission denied )`

and the output  from library PhpVideoToolKit

`sh: /root/bin/ffmpeg: Permission denied`

how can i give permission for execute to my apache service? i'm used  CENTOS

- [Here an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YfoG.png)
- [here an image of the return exec command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRE0V.png)

Comment: try `chown nobody:nobody /root/bin/ffmpeg` or `chown apache:apache /root/bin/ffmpeg` ... depend what is user of apache

Comment: Thanks. i'm try with apache that is the user and restart the service, but but not work.

Comment: Actually, if you want to run this from PHP you need to set permissions for the user running PHP scripts, not Apache. This depends on what extension you're using. Eg. with suEXEC https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache,_suEXEC_and_Virtual_Hosts?

Comment: Also, as a note, probably don't execute as root.

Comment: how can i execute as root?

Comment: because i'm try in ubuntu and the execution is normal, but in centos don't work... :S

Answer (score 0):

Well, first in Centos OS we need give to apache or www-data perssions for execute:

Edit sudoers

```
nano /etc/sudoers
```

Comment requiretty line

```
#Defaults    requiretty
```

Add the line at the final of the file

```
apache  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And now we can execute the command over PHP

```
exec('sudo /root/bin/ffmpeg -v',$output);
print_r($ouput);
```

and the output is that

```
    Array ( 
[0] => ffmpeg version git-2016-07-03-1ad4471 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers 
[1] => built with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55) ...
```

Thats works!